# Infinite intersection and limits

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm having difficulty understanding the relationship between a limit and an infinite intersection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, suppose we take any non-increasing sequence of numbers $x_n$ such that $x_n > a$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=a$ then how is
$$ (-\infty,a]=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty,x_n]?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Since each component of the right side obviously contains the left side, we see the left is contained in the right. If the left contains anything the right does, then $x_n$ wouldn't limit to $a$.

Comment: When in doubt, check the two set inclusions that define set equality.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. Showing the left side in the right is fine but I'm a little unsure on the right side in the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right inclusion:

Suppose $y\in\bigcap_1^\infty (-\infty, x_n]$. We claim that $y\leq a$.

For suppose $y>a$, say $\varepsilon = y-a>0$. Since $x_n\to a$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Since $x_n>a$, we can remove the absolute values to say that $x_n-a<\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon = y-a$, substituting we obtain $0<x_n-a<y-a$, that is $$x_n<y$$ for all $n\geq N$.

But then $y\notin (-\infty, x_n]$ for $n\geq N$, contradicting our choice of $y$. Therefore we conclude that $y\leq a$, so $y\in(-\infty, a]$.